# Why class name "B" has to be explicitly specified when passing "&B::f1" as argument?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Why is it necessary that passing a non-static function pointer `B::f1` as a  parameter of a function `cFunc()` **requires** the explicit class name `B::`?

Here is a compilable code.  I doubt why the line [1] is ok, but [2] is fail.

```
class C{
    public: template<class BI> void cFunc(
        BI* bPtr,
        void (BI::*bF1 )() )
        {
            auto sys_crashListener = std::bind(bF1, *bPtr);
    }
};
class B{
    void f1(){ }    
    void test(){
        C* cPtr;
        cPtr->setCrashListener(this,&B::f1); //ok  [1]
        //cPtr->setCrashListener(this,&f1); //compile fail  [2]
        // compile error "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified"
    }   
};
```

I am at the local scope of `B`, so it is sure to be `B::`.
Why has C++ been designed to **not** make deduction like that?

Is there an easy way / trick (e.g. add very short code) to enforce the deduction?

Comment: Because the language designer felt it us the most safe, simple and consistent ways to refer to pointers to members.

Comment: I see you love java from declaring the member function on the same line with the access specifier `public :`

Comment: @bolov the OP's name wasn't a dead-giveaway ?

Comment: @bolov Is that a *so* bad practice?  It is my habit - the style of code that make me sleep well & feel like at home.  If so, I will try to change it.

Comment: @javaLover any "practice" that (a) does NOT make an anonymous developer want to gouge their own eyes out with a spoon while reading your code, and (b) makes it easier for you to code, *in that order*, is likely worthy.

Comment: @javaLover is not suited in C++ as you have one access specifier for more members. It makes sense on java where each member has his own access specifier.

Comment: @bolov  For more member, I will just public: public: public:  private: ... every function / field.  Is it still not ok?   This way, when I look at a certain function, I can just look at the accessibility-level near it (not have to scroll). XD

Comment: `Is there an easy way / trick (e.g. add very short code) to enforce the deduction?` You could use `&std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type::f1`

Comment: @javaLover If you are concerned about excessive scrolling: maybe you should be more concerned about whether your class has too many methods or is doing too many different things.

Comment: @W.F. Jesus that is like pulling out a nail with an excavator.

Comment: @javaLover oh and if you have `public private public public private public private private public private private private public public` in that order you better make sure the next programmer that has to work with your code doesn't know where you live.

Comment: @bolov haha I like your metaphore :) I'm not saying it's the best idea just explicitly answering the question :)